# StepVerifier project reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm using springboot 3.1.3 and springwebflux

I'm not understanding how to set up unit tests.

Let's suppose I have a simple service like this:

```
private Mono<Boolean> sendMessage(String uri, String msg){
        return Mono.just(fhir).flatMap(fh ->{
            final URI theURi;
            try {
                theURi = new URI(uri);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return this.oauth2WebClientPnt
                        .post()
                        .uri(theURi)
                        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(msg)
                        .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                        })
                        .retrieve()
                        //.onStatus(httpStatusCode -> HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR == httpStatusCode, clientResponse -> Mono.empty())
                        .bodyToMono(Boolean.class);
        });
}
```

What is the best approach to test this method by using StepVerifier?

My last test was:

```
        StepVerifier
                .create(sendMessage(uri, fhir))
                .expectNextMatches(result -> result == Boolean.TRUE)
                .verifyComplete();
```

But no HTTP call is done

May you give me a tip? What is the best practice to test reactive functions?

Comment: You code looks alright. Do you get an error or a suspicious log somewhere ?

Comment: It simply doesn't make the web call